# Write a SOQL Query to extract queue memebers

Tags: soql, query, queue, public-group

How do I write a SOQL query for the developer console that extracts the names of the names of the queue members buried within a public group inside the queue?

Comment: I"m stuck writing the query because I haven't done this before but I know I should be able to do via a query.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Select Id from Group where type='Queue' and Name='Queue Name']
```

Queues are stored as records in the table Group with 'Type' as "Queue".

Use this Id of the queue in the query

`[Select UserOrGroupId From GroupMember where GroupId =:reqdGroupId]`

to fetch all the users or groups which are members of the required queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't been able to get the query to work. I keep on getting the error message "Unknown error parsing query.  For example, where is the query I wrote for obtainn the memebers of a group associated to a queue.

SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, GroupId = "00G70000001ufN9EAI" FROM GroupMember

Comment: it will go like this -> Select id,UserOrGroupId,Groupid,SystemModstamp From GroupMember where GroupId ='00G7F000000jgw9UAA'(queueid)